For two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$, What is it called if $\frac{f_1}{f_2}$ is upper and lower bounded by positive constants?
For two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ defined on a domain D, suppose there exists two positive constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that
\begin{equation}
0<c_1\leq \inf\limits_{x\in D}\frac{f_1(x)}{f_2(x)}\leq \sup\limits_{x\in D}\frac{f_1(x)}{f_2(x)}\leq c_2.
\end{equation}
I wonder if there exists any terminology to describe such relation between $f_1$ and $f_2$.

This is sometimes written $f_1(x) = \Theta(f_2(x))$, see here.

Thanks, the math notation is well-known. Is there any word to describe the `same order' relation? I want to search something related to this on line.
